# How can I Iterate through list of records using its element id from a javascript file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I have a Customer and Order Models and passing all Rates record as a list to a partial view. From the partial view I am calling a JavaScript as an external JavaScript file. Also passing Rates into that JavaScript file. How can I iterate each record in Csutomer Rates in the JavaScript. I am trying to iterate each record of Customer Rates . Here is my code

```
public class Customer()
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  pubic string CustomerName {get;set;}
  public List<CustomerRate> Rates {get;set;}  
}

public CustomerRate()
{
  pubic int CustomerId {get;set;}
  public decimal Rate {get;set;}
}

public class Order()
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  pubic int CustomerId {get;set;}
  public DateTime OrderDate {get;set;}
  public List<CustomerRate> Rates {get;set;} 
}
```

from Customer Controller I am passing Rates

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
  Customer customer = New Customer()
  customer.Rates= db.CustomerRate.ToList()
  return ('CustomerView',customer )
}
```

In Customer.cshtml

```
@Model Customer
Order order = new Order();
order.Rates= Model.Rates;
<div>
     @Html.Partial("_OrderLine", order)
</div>
In _OrderLine partial View
<div>
    @html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Rates, new{id="Rates"})
</div>
<script>
   "Order.js"
<script
```

In Order.js

```
var rates = document.getElementById('Rates');
```

How can I iterate rates to find each record

Answer (score 0):

> How can I iterate each record in Csutomer Rates in the JavaScript. I
> am trying to iterate each record of Customer Rates

Well, first of all, within your partial view extract the C# object list or Enumerable list as as [@Html.Raw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.raw?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) by Serializing json model.

Furthermore, you should parse that collection into json object by using [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). Thus, you are good to go for executing the iteration over the collection which will provide you the item element within the array.

However, it would be hard and costly to retrieve the element by its IDs so that you need to execute loop twice which would cost similar to O(n^2) big O complexity.

Now, let's have a look in practice how we can do that in practice:

Demo Model:

```
public class Todo
 {
     
     public int ItemId { get; set; }
     
     public string Description { get; set; }
     
     public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
     
     public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
     
     
}
```

Demo Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{

    return View(ListOfTodos);
}
```

**Note:** Just returning the simple list object

View:

```
@model IEnumerable< DotNet6MVCWebApp.Models.Todo>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    int count = 0;
}


@section scripts {
    <script>

        var arrayOfArrays = '@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model))';
        console.log("Raw object: "+arrayOfArrays);
       
     
        for (var result of JSON.parse(arrayOfArrays)) {
            document.write(result.description + "<br />");
            console.log("Json values: " + result.description);
        }
    </script>
}
```

**Note:** Pass this object `@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model)` to your partial view and then extract using `JSON.parse(arrayOfArrays)` and continue your iteration.

Output:

[image]

[image]